# Downloading while uploading in cloud storage

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, soundcloud

Is there a cloud storage system that enables to upload video and audio to the cloud. While uploading a third party is authorized to download in real time or near real time the uploaded stream (video or audio)?

Comment: You want to stream audio or video? You can stream with YouTube.

Comment: Can I restrict it to specific user or group of users?

Comment: Only if those users all have a Google/YouTube account.